# MSSQL: Export Wizard, not possible to save SSIS Package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms

short question, is there a problem while trying to save a SSIS Package from the export wizard when the management studio is version 2016 and the SQL server is version 2014?

Errormessage is:

> In SQL Server Express, Web, or Workgroup, you can run the package that the Import and Export Wizard creates, but cannot save it. To save packages that the wizard creates, you must upgrade to SQL Server Standard, Enterprise, Developer or Evaluation.

SSMS Version: 13.0.15600.2
SQL Server Version: 12.0.4416.0

License Information via:

> SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'), SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')

Output:

> 12.0.4416.0, SP1, Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit)

If I try the same on the server, with ssms 12.0.4416.0, there isn't any problem.

Thank you in advance.

edit: found the solution:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238486.aspx

> 3. SSMS can only connect to SQL Server 2016 Integrated Services (SSIS 2016) instances.
>      There is a known compatibility limitation with SQL Server Integration Services that prevents connecting to previous versions.
>      As a workaround for this problem, you can connect to your SQL Server Integration Service instance by using the SSMS release aligned with your SSIS instance.

Comment: The error message seems to indicate that SSMS Version: 13.0.15600.2 (is Sql Express, web or workgroup), while SQL Server Version: 12.0.4416.0 (is Standard, enterprise or development)

Comment: Afaik there is only one version of managment studio 2016: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx 12 is version 2014 while 13 is version 2016

Comment: Sorry Scott, found the answer (3.): 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238486.aspx

Comment: Please [repost your solution as an answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) instead of including it into the question. Thank you, and welcome to the site!

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of SSMS too. Your version is old as the latest version fixes the issue when you couldn't save SSIS package from Import/Export Wizard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit: found the solution: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238486.aspx

SSMS can only connect to SQL Server 2016 Integrated Services (SSIS 2016) instances. There is a known compatibility limitation with SQL Server Integration Services that prevents connecting to previous versions. As a workaround for this problem, you can connect to your SQL Server Integration Service instance by using the SSMS release aligned with your SSIS instance.